# Need a custom function to be accessible throughout WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, notifications, call

I have this notification function and need to call it in different places of the code. I need to put it some where which be accessed by any files inside my child theme as well as in the plugins directory.

```
function send_notification($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = My_Token',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
}
```

- **First question, Where to put it, currently it is in functions.php?**
- **Second question, how to call it in different places?**

Any solution and reference would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've got a function with a broad scope, consider giving it a more unique name to prevent naming conflicts, such as `naser_send_notitification()` instead of just `send_notification`, or if you can - consider using a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) or [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Now to answer your question, `functions.php` is actually usually a safe bet for "broad scope" functions that need to be accessible just about anywhere. If you look at the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you'll see that `after_setup_theme` is fired relatively early-on, allowing your function to be accessible from that hook or later - since it will be available during this moment. However, it does come after `plugins_loaded`, so if you need it before then, you'll need to turn it into a plugin with a [File Header](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) or an "MU Plugin".

If you need it be accessible at effectively the earliest momement, consider putting it in a file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` and give it a name, even something like `custom-functions.php`. These files are called [Must-Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). Files in this directory are always loaded, and always run before anything else, so functions declared in them are accessible incredibly early. This is typically where I put code I need to make sure is theme independent, is always on and can't be deactivated.

So effectively:

1) Rename your function to something a bit more unique, like `naser_send_notitification()`

2) Put this code in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-funtions.php`

3) Now you should be able to call `naser_send_notification( $tokens, $message )` in any function or hook that comes after the [`muplugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded) hook (which is just about anywhere)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Solution:
every thing is commented on  each line

```
function do_something( $a = "", $b = "" ) { // create your function
    echo '<code>';
        print_r( $a ); // `print_r` the array data inside the 1st argument
    echo '</code>';

    echo '<br />'.$b; // echo linebreak and value of 2nd argument
}

add_action( 'danish', 'do_something', 10, 2 ); 
// create your own action with params('action name', 'callback funtion', priority, num_of params)
```

then **Hook** everywhere you need

```
    $a = array(
    'eye patch'  => 'yes',
    'parrot'     => true,
    'wooden leg' => 1
);
$b = __( 'And Hook said: "I ate ice cream with Peter Pan."', 'textdomain' ); 

// Executes the action hook named 'danish'

do_action('danish', $a, $b);
```

that's it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [wordpress shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) would be the best approach to handle this. Because messing with wordpress core files is not good practice and leads to several issues like code removal on upgrade etc.

There are several benefits of shortcodes and for your specific problem it would be beneficial because:

- can be placed in parent/child themes `functions.php`
- can be accessible in `php` code files and in dashboard editor as well

**Complete Code:** (just place inside `functions.php`)

```
function send_notification( $atts )
{

  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "tokens" => '',
    "message" => ''
  ), $atts));

  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $tokens,
    'data' => $message
  );
  $headers = array(
    'Authorization:key = My_Token',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;

}

add_shortcode('send-notification', 'send_notification');
```

**Call it anywhere in theme or plugin:** (like this)

1. wordpress editor:

   ```
   [send-notification token=XXXX message="hello"]
   ```
2. theme/plugin files:

   ```
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[send-notification token=XXXX message="hello"]'); ?>
   ```

**Useful Resources:**

1. WordPress [Shortcode with Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/)
2. A [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-to-list-posts-with-multiple-parameters--wp-32199) on Wordpress Shortcodes
3. [Creating Shortcode](https://speckyboy.com/getting-started-with-wordpress-shortcodes-examples/) with different type of parameters

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615118/wordpress-accessing-a-plugins-function-from-a-theme) :
step 1: write your function into a class inside your plugin
step 2: create an object of that class into your theme
step 3: access your function by that object.

```
// inside your plugin 
class foo {
      public function send_notification() {
            return "whatever you want";
   }
}

// inside your themes functions.php
$foo_object = new foo();

// use the object to access your function:
$foo_object->send_notification();
```